# Perl Regex "Not" (negative lookahead)

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm not terribly certain what the correct wording for this type of regex would be, but basically what I'm trying to do is match any string that starts with "/" but is not followed by "bob/", as an example.

So these would match:

```
/tom/
/tim/
/steve
```

But these would not

```
tom
tim
/bob/
```

I'm sure the answer is terribly simple, but I had a difficult time searching for "regex not" anywhere. I'm sure there is a fancier word for what I want that would pull good results, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Edit: I've changed the title to indicate the correct name for what I was looking for

Comment: what about `/jimbob/`?   what about `/bob/apples`?

Comment: For my purposes /jimbob/ was okay, but /bob/apples was not

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead (documented under ["Extended Patterns" in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)):

```
/^\/(?!bob\/)/
```

Comment: Probably /^\/(?!bob\/)/ , though-- but you got the gist of it. Thanks!

Comment: @GoldenNewby Woops, overlooked that part of the question

Comment: With default regex flags now a feature, that `^` is better written as `\A`. With alternate delimiters and `/x`, it looks like `m| \A / (?!bob/) |x`.

Comment: @brian d foy, It's preposterous to suggest the existence this feature means `/^/` has to be changed to `/\A/`, `/$/` to `/(?=\n?\z)/`, `/./` to `/[^\n]/` and `/ /` to `/[ ]/`.

Comment: @ikegami: `$` should be `\z` more often than not anyway; I am not without appreciation for a reason to use the parallel `\A`

Answer (score 8):

### TLDR: Negative Lookaheads

If you wanted a negative lookahead just to find `"foo"` when it isn't followed by `"bar"`...

```
$string =~ m/foo(?!bar)/g;
```

[**Working Demo Online**](https://ideone.com/k6HEcK)

### Source

To quote the docs...

> `(?!pattern)`
>
> `(*nla:pattern)`
>
> `#(*negative_lookahead:pattern)`
>
> A zero-width negative lookahead assertion. For example `/foo(?!bar)/` matches any occurrence of "foo" that isn't followed by "bar". Note however that lookahead and lookbehind are NOT the same thing. You cannot use this for lookbehind. (Source: [**PerlDocs**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions).)

### Negative Lookaheads For Your Case

The accepted answer is great, but it leaves no explanation, so let me add one...

```
/^\/(?!bob\/)/
```

- `^` — Match only the start of strings.
- `\/` — Match the `/` char, which we need to escape because it is a character in the regex format (i.e. `s/find/replacewith/`, etc.).
- `(?!...)` — Do not match if the match is followed by `...`.
- `bob\/` — This is the `...` value, don't match `bob/', once more, we need to escape the` /`.